# Return Array of Index of Capital Letters AS3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, indexing

I would like to take a normal string, and return an array with the indexes of the capital letters only.

So basically:

var str1:String = "TexT STufF"
var capArray = [0,3,5,6,9]

I am able to do it for spaces like this:

```
for(var n5=0; n5 < str1.length; n5++)
    {
        numSpace = str1.indexOf(" ", numSpace+1); //That space is what determines it. How do I make it search for all Caps?
        if(numSpace == -1)
        {
            n5 = str1.length;
        }
        else{arySpaceInd[n5] = numSpace;}
    }
    trace(aryVerse);
```

Is it possible to do it for capitals?

Comment: Character is in upper case when this gives `true` : `if(char == char.toUpperCase())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Cherniv pointed out, just convert each character in the sequence to upper case and check if it's the same. If it is, it's a capital letter. Function example:

```
function getIndexes(input:String):Vector.<int>
{
    var output:Vector.<int> = new <int>[];
    for(var i:int = 0; i < input.length; i++)
    {
        if(input.charAt(i).toUpperCase() === input.charAt(i))
        {
            output.push(i);
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```

And the test:

```
trace(getIndexes("SomeUpperCaseText")); // 0,4,9,13
```

Answer (score 1):

I would (*mis*)use [`string#replace()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#replace%28%29) for this... Something like this should work:

```
function getIndexes(input:String):Vector.<int>
{
    var output:Vector.<int> = new <int>[];
    input.replace(/[A-Z]/g, function(match,ndx) { output.push(ndx); return match; });
    return output;
}
```